# LinkedIn and google plus share successful callback

Tags: google-plus, linkedin-api

I got callback after share successfully with Facebook and Twitter.
Is it possible with Linkedin and Google Plus?

Google Plus Share :

```
href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}"
```

Linkedin Share :

```
href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={articleUrl}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Linkedin Share widget](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator)

Set callback function on `onsuccess` that fires when share successfully:

```
<script type="IN/Share+init" data-counter="top" data-url="your share Url" data-onsuccess="tracklinkedin"></script>
```

On `tracklinkedin` function:

```
function tracklinkedin(reponse) {
   console.log('linkedin' + reponse);
   //do here
}
```

Google Plus:

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="top" data-href="your url"    data-callback="trackgoogle" ></div>

function trackgoogle(reponse) {
     console.log('Google Plus' + reponse.state);
    if(reponse.state=='on')   
    {
      $SS.TrackCount('googleplus')
      //to do
    }}
```

Comment: This appears to be broken since April 2014. There is a LinkedIn Developer thread here: https://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2805

Answer (score 1):

Just make your own button, with its own callback, and you can ditch the LinkedIn Share Button API SDK, JS Bundle, and inShare plugins.  Some of these appear to already be outdated, deprecated, and to have known issues.  All you really ought to need is...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Then you can just make any button, using any HTML, CSS, or JavaScript that you like, and hyperlink it to allow sharing of a page.  Since it's just a native button, you can control the callback however you like.  And make a callback however you'd like...

HTML...

```
<a id="link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}">Share on LinkedIn</a>
```

JS...

```
$('#link').click(function(e) { //callback stuff });
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

Google is probably a similar situation.  If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of these URL formats so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]